# Notify new deployed AWS Lambda functions in Slack bot

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bots, slack

We use Serverless Framework to deploy our Lambda functions in a custom Lambda deployment script in Python.

Many of the developers are using this lambda deployment script to deploy our lambda functions.

They don't always remember to tag the version in git and also it's not an indicator to what is currently deployed.

Is there a way to inform which Lambda function's version was deployed in some slack bot channel or something?

I think it requires some tagging in each lambda function code.

If there's a way to avoid going through each lambda it will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should be splitting your problem in two parts.

1. How to get lambda function name(s) and version dynamically
2. and how to publish relevant information to monitoring agent

For the first you should look for [list functions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.list_functions) and collect required information.

for 2nd one you probably need to implement a solution if you don't have anything in place.

Comment: Thanks.

Umm, about the versioning in step 1.
I have to implement a certain boto3 code in each lambda for that to happen?
Would love a more central area where all lambdas notify their version according to a central configuration.

Comment: @Amit123 No you don't have to run code for any specific lambda, boto3 code should give you details of all deployed lambda's and version details. however you would need process that response and collect required information

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.
I want as soon as one lambda from a list of lambdas is deployed, to notify via slack.
I need to run another lambda that checks for version differences from the ls command?

Other option I see is add a code in each lambda that will notify to slack.